# Can't export SQL results as excel file when commas are in the description column text

Tags: sql, excel

I am seeing an issue here. I have a sql database with over 10,000 records. There is a description column that contains user input from our support website. Some users put commas into their description for grammar purposes. When I go to export my sql results as a excel file, the commas in the user description text mess up the arrangement of the file. I need to export as what's in the SQL cells and not every time it sees a comma. Please help?

Comment: Yes because I need to store the file in SQL, to save an audit trail, then modify it for later on.

Comment: What system are you talking about - **SQL Server** (then please add `sql-server` as a tag), or SQL with MS Access (then please add `ms-access`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I also did a replace within the database and replaced all the commas with a space, and then replaced all the tabs and line breaks with a space as well. The new line delimiter was making excel think it was a new cell. I opened the excel file in notepad++ to see all of the LF's and CRLF's and then just searched+replaced the ascii sequence of the two in SQL with a space. LF's, commas, and tabs, are all non important characters to preserve. Thanks again. -Chris

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you wrap each output field in quotes, Excel should know to treat that as one field.

I hope this helps.